# Can i exclude certain fields from being documented in history of TFS workitems?

Tags: tfs, workitem

I wrote a plugin that saves and updates a certain numeric field which is part of the layout of a workitem in the TFS.

The problem is, a lot of updates \ changes are done in the backend on this field, and when someone reviews the history tab of the workitem, they can see a lot of these changes documented, when they have no real added value being documented, and simply clutter the history view.

is there a way to configure the TFS \ save a workitem in the backend and have that change excluded from the history logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not possible, nor have we any plans to avoid adding it to the history. Any change to a work item creates a new revision, and we want to keep that for auditing purposes. However we are working to improve the history control and one of the future improvements will be to visually filter out changes made by the system.

This is great info as we are designing the next version of the history control on the work item form.